# Python - big data regression

Tags: python, bigdata, regression, glm

Right now I'm trying to run a regression on a large set of data that contains about 20 million rows and 30 columns worth of data. Unfortunately, about half of these columns need to be read in as strings for which I'm going to have to expand into dummy variables for the regression. Here is some code that I'm currently using to split it into train/ test datasets:

```
final = pd.read_csv('./data.csv')
msk = np.random.rand(len(final)) < 0.55
train = final[msk]
test = final[~msk]


#Training and testing with Poisson model
print('Regression Time: ', dt.now(), '\n')
res1 = smf.glm(formula=output + ' ~ ' + variables, data=train, offset=np.log(train[offset]), family=sm.families.Poisson(sm.families.links.log())).fit()
```

I am running the above regression but have never run it on this size of data. I know how to format any dummy columns as np.int8 datatypes to reduce the memory taken up by these values but don't know how to handle this kind of problem or big data in general very well. I feel like even just reading my data into the dataframe is inefficient somehow even when specifying the datatypes of each column. This program typically crashes on me about 20 minutes into the run. I'd appreciate any pointers with how to deal with this data effectively and if there is even a solution to running a regression at this scale.

I'm still a novice at working with big data and would appreciate any help with this problem, thanks in advance

Comment: Suggestion: Do you really need to perform linear regression on all your observations? Take a few subsets, run the regression and check your coefficients.. They should not deviate that much.

Comment: I think I can do that, do you know if there is a way to process large data more efficiently? I see people talking about how they can process gigabytes of data relatively easily but my program seems to be struggling with even loading and regressing 1 gigabyte of data

Comment: You could try h2o. It includes a fantastic GLM implementation.